# Create simple gui using qtdesigner

Tags: qt, user-interface

I want to create a gui, if it means implementing the code, where do I implement the code? And how to run the qtdesigener?

Comment: Can you please specify a bit more, on which platform you are? What IDE are you using? Are you using qt project files, CMake or perhaps Visual Studio project files? For detailed instructions I'd need this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Qt Designer, or Qt Creator which is a full developement environment (IDE) not just a GUI designer. Visit this site http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

Each window or widget in Qt generally is defined in 3 files:

some_name.ui       - this file is generated by Qt Designer or Qt creator.
some_name.h        - this is the C++ header file that contains Class declaration
some_name.cpp      - this file contains C++ class implementation

some_name ofourse is the name of your widget/window.

When You add new windows/widgets to your Qt project you have to modify Your *.pro file which contains information on how to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial shows a hello world in qt creator:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLT7oEt6gLE
I hope this is what you were looking for.